# How to create declare with pdo

Tags: php, sql-server

Hello how to create this declare with SQL-Server.

```
$charItems = $conn->prepare("DECLARE @item varbinary(3792); SET @item
= (SELECT Inventory FROM Character WHERE Name='".$userCharsDrop['Name']."'); print @item"); $characterItems =
 $charItems->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Result of this is code is:

```
Array
(
)

Array
(
)
```

Comment: `DECLARE` can only be used inside a stored procedure. You don't need to declare variables that begin with `@`.

Comment: There's no `PRINT` statement in SQL.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.? Add the appropriate tag to the question.

Comment: Okay, can you give me more details.So it does because it keeps my returns an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `DECLARE`. You should also use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection attacks.

This code should work for you:

```
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT inventory FROM character WHERE name=:name");
$sth->bindParam(":name", $userCharsDrop['Name']);
$sth->execute();
$charItems = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

You may want to tweak parameters for `fetchAll`. Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: Wrong solution. This returns 255 characters only. It should return 3792 characters.

Comment: @garp, you should post a separate question describing your issue in better details. Prepared statements by themselves have no explicit string length limitations. This is most likely related to some MySQL quirk you are hitting, or using it improperly.